# Is there a way to switch Mac OS boot partitions without going through System Preferences?

Tags: bootcamp, mojave, catalina, dual-boot

I have just viewed a YouTube video on how to set up my Mac as a Mojave/Catalina dual-boot, using two APFS volumes on the internal drive, instead of using a bootable external drive.

But is there a way to select the boot OS without having to go into System Preferences every time I want to switch? And is there a way that's compatible with the bootable APFS volumes being encrypted?

So far, everything I've seen online about Boot Camp seems to indicate that it's strictly for setting up a Mac/WinDoze dual-boot. Am I mistaken? Can it do what I want here?

By comparison, my DOS/Linux dual boot at home boots to a GRUB menu, that allows me to select the desired OS (PC-DOS 2000 or Ubuntu Hardy Heron), defaulting to whatever OS I used last.

Comment: Have you tried installing GRUB to dual boot macOS?

Comment: Yes - Boot Camp is for Windows only.

Comment: You may be able to use `systemsetup`. It documents `-liststartupdisks` and `-setstartupdisk` options, though on my machine (with only one boot disk), `-liststartupdisks` only displays `/System/Library/CoreServices`, which looks very much *not* like a startup disk to me. (Maybe on another machine, it would list something like `/Volumes/SomeOtherDisk/System/LibraryCoreServices` as well?)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can hold down the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> key (also known as <kbd>Alt</kbd>) at startup, and that will show you all the available boot volumes.

Comment: If you hold down the control key when making your selection, then the selection will become the default.

Comment: I think I remember that, from back when my "bionic desk lamp" iMac at home still had ROMs that could boot the MacOS 9 partition. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 9):

If you want a boot manger which behaves similar to GRUB, the you could install [rEFInd](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/). This free boot manager is similar, because rEFInd can be configured to display a menu of operating system choices for a specified period of seconds, then automatically choose the last used if the period expires.

Comment: rEFInd is a good recommendation. It was designed & built as a tool for EFI-based machines. The developer knows his stuff.

Comment: I'll research it when I get a chance, although I think the Option key is probably adequate.

Answer (score 1):

There's the `bless` command, if you're into typing commands. It's here on a 10.12.6 system; don't know if Apple removed it in later releases. Maybe something like:

```
bless --mount "/Volumes/OtherOS" --setBoot
```

Comment: `bless` is still around, but has been gradually losing most of its usefulness since OS X 10.11, when SIP prevented it from doing anything useful (nor harmful). With EFI boot to APFS drives that is the norm nowadays, `bless` is very tricky to use correctly, to put it mildly. On systems with the T2 chip, the only useful invocation that I am aware of is `sudo bless --info` to find out the inode of the booter file. `systemsetup -setstartupdisk` is what you're supposed to use to set the startup disk from the command line, though I don't think that works on T2 systems either.